# iOS Push Notifications - Extreme Unreliability

Tags: ios, notifications, push

I'm very aware that APNS is not supposed to be a reliable service but I'm getting about a very low success rate, which is frustrating as I'm not sure if it's an APNS problem or my problem. I've set up my app to register remote notifications and they will come through - but rarely and sometimes after around ten minutes. If I restart my device, it struggles to receive any push notifications again.

Has anyone else suffered incredibly low/high delay notification times? Is there anything that I could be doing to exacerbate this problem?

Answer (score 1):

APNS works well as it should work. I have implemented more than 15 apps even chat as well. There is no problem with APNS.
If you are getting delay may be a network issue. Please check your connection.
Best example of APNS implementation have a look if you need:- https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes push notifications may delay.
This problem may occurred form your server system.
Usually i am following the below trick so that push notifications are getting properly.

**Trick:** Restart your server system this may fasten your push notifications delivery

**Note**: Be sure that you have uploaded your pem file in the server